# Distribution of chromosomes in sample of sperm cells

Tags: probability, classification, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, genetics

Presumably in an ejaculation sample from a human, each sperm cell contains half of the chromosomes from a full cell.
Hence every chromosome is equally present in the cells of a sperm sample.

However, has anyone analyzed the frequency of each pair of chromosomes appearing together in a sperm sample?

That is, if there are n chromosomes, then there are C(n, 2) pairs. If we list these pairs on the x-axis of a histogram, we could record for each sperm cell in a sample of N sperm cells how many times the specific combination occurred.

We could repeat listing C(n, 3) on the x-axis, counting the frequency of triples, all the way to having an x-axis of the C(n,n/2) combinations, each of which would correspond to a single sperm cell type.

So, we would have n/2-1 histograms that could be analyzed graphically to see something about how chromosomes tend to occur together or not in sperm cell samples.

Thank you if you know of any such work.

Presumably it is simple to sequence each cell in turn in a sperm sample.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing how one would construct a useful histogram representing $\binom{46}{23}\approx 8\times 10^{12}$ categories. In fact, it starts getting difficult at $\binom{46}{3}=15180$.

Comment: That's part of the question. Yes, that's true, but at least for C(n,2) it's easy (one could use a scrollbar). For the rest, one could record the frequencies of each combinatorial coefficient, treating all coefficients C(n,m) with equal m the same, and record the probability that each count occurs with a certain value or within a certain interval, then plot the distribution.

Comment: You seem to want to know how much of the sperm cells has a wrong combination of chromosomes. Note however that the chromosomes are not selected randomly when the meiosis happens, so unless there is an error you won't get all the combinations whuber mentions. And even an error happens normali it will happen in very low frequency.

Comment: As @Llopis says, you won't choose from 46. There are 23 pairs, and a sperm cell choses one from each pair, which leads to a total of $2^{23}$ choices.